# Measuring execution time of a function running in the while loop in C++ (windows)

Tags: c++, windows, function, while-loop, execution-time

everybody , I have a project in windows platform and I wanna to measure execution time of several functions in a while loop  (picture3),so i create a class (called Benchmark, picture 1 the header and picture 2 is the code source) that do that however,  it's execute the time in every step (picrture 4) but   I want to know how much time program spends totally on each function .any idea please.

```
// Benchmrak.cpp
#define time Now() std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
#define duration(a) std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds (a).count();
Benchmark:: Benchmark(std::string caller, bool start_running=false ) :_caller(caller), _elapsed(0), _running(false),average (0),count(0)
{
if (start_running ) start(); 
}

//-------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark:: ~Benchmark()
{
  stop();
 //average_time();
  disp ();

}

//-------------------------------------------------------

void Benchmark:: start() 
{
 if (!_running) //=if (runing==false)
 {
     _start_time=timeNow();
     _running = true;
 }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------
void Benchmark:: stop() 
{

 if (_running ) 
 {
     stop_time=timeNow(); 
     _elapsed= duration(stop_time - _start_time);
     average =_elapsed;
     _running = false;
       count   ;
 }
}
void Benchmark:: disp() 
{ 

 std::cout<<std::fixed<<std::setprecision(4);
 std::cout<<"Time taking for "<<_caller<<" is : "<< _elapsed /1.e9 <<"s\n"; 

// in another file.Cpp contain while loop
 while( _continue )
 {
     //std::cout<<"Image number "<<m_imgIdx<<std::endl;
     //read image
     AbbeTIFFReader_getSampleData( m_tiff, mat.data, 0);
     _continue = AbbeTIFFReader_readNext( m_tiff );

     cv::add ( mat, matConcatenated, matConcatenated, cv::noArray(),CV_32FC1 );

     Benchmark tim_1 ("LocalMean",true);
     //local mean
     cv::Mat mat_LocalMean = m_substractLocalMean(mat,15);  //1st function
     tim_1.stop();
     //wavelet
     double stdDev =0;
     Benchmark tim_2("matWavel et",true);
     cv::Mat matWavelet = m_WaveletFiltering (mat_LocalMean,stdDev); //2nd function
     tim_2.stop();

     //fast    
      Benchmark tim_3 ("fastLoc",true);        
      m_fastLoc(matWavelet,stdDev,1.,9,50); //3rd function
     tim_3.stop();
     tim_1.disp ();
     tim_2.disp ();
     tim_3.disp ();


      m_imgIdx  ;
// the exution 
 }`*********** iam in startLocalization function *************
void Localization::startLocalization()
Time taking for LocalMean is : 0.0000s
Time taking for matWavel et is : 0.0000s
Time taking for fastLoc is : 0.0010s
Time taking for LocalMean is : 0.0000s
Time taking for matWavel et is : 0.0000s
Time taking for fastLoc is : 0.0010s
Time taking for LocalMean is : 0.0000s
Time taking for matWavel et is : 0.0000s
Time taking for fastLoc is : 0.0010s
Time taking for LocalMean is : 0.0000s
Time taking for matWavel et is : 0.0000s
Time taking for fastLoc is : 0.0010s
Time taking for LocalMean is : 0.0000s
Time taking for matWavel et is : 0.0000s
Time taking for fastLoc is : 0.0010s
Time taking for LocalMean is : 0.0000s
Time taking for matWavel et is : 0.0000s
Time taking for fastLoc is : 0.0010s
Time taking for LocalMean is : 0.0000s
Time taking for matWavel et is : 0.0000s
Time taking for fastLoc is : 0.0010s
Time taking for LocalMean is : 0.0000s
Time taking for matWavel et is : 0.0000s
Time taking for fastLoc is : 0.0010s
Time taking for LocalMean is : 0.0000s
Time taking for matWavel et is : 0.0000s
Time taking for fastLoc is : 0.0010s
```

Comment: Maybe you need to print in ms instead of in seconds because the actual time is so small.

Comment: Where is your code for `disp()` and `timeNow()`

Comment: // Benchmark.cpp
#define time Now() std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
#define duration(a) std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(a).count();
for disp it is function fo display a message 
void Benchmark:: disp() 
{ 
    
    std::cout<<std::fixed<<std::setprecision(4);
    std::cout<<"Time taking for "<<_caller<<" is : "<< _elapsed /1.e9 <<"s\n"; 

}

Comment: do you have any idea how solve it please.thank you for answer

Comment: Change `std::cout<<"Time taking for "<<_caller<<" is : "<< _elapsed /1.e9 <<"s\n"; ` to `std::cout<<"Time taking for "<<_caller<<" is : "<< _elapsed /1.e6 <<"ms\n";`

Comment: actually I did what did you say but nothing changes only the results is number of the time but me I want to display only one number of time for each function